# Rasa Webchat Integration issue

Tags: python, socket.io, rasa-core, rasa

Hey I'm new to Rasa so when I try to run my chatbot using the command

```
rasa run --credentials credentials.yml --cors null
```

the chatbot runs only when I open the HTML file using its path.

```
file:///C:/Users/ansel/PycharmProjects/rasabot/index.html
```

Hence I wanted to know if there is any way to run the HTML file on my localhost?
When I enter http://localhost:5005 in my browser it gives me :
*Hello from Rasa: 1.8.1*
and not the actual webpage

Also on the same note when I re-run the rasa chatbot is doesn't seem to clear my old conversation.....is there any way to change this??

My chatbot also doesn't seem to load any images.

[image: This is the issue I face currently.]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rasa Chatbot</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="webchat"/>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/mrbot-cdn/webchat-latest.js"></script>
// Or you can replace latest with a specific version
<script>
  WebChat.default.init({
    selector: "#webchat",
    initPayload: "/hello",
    customData: {"language": "en"}, // arbitrary custom data. Stay minimal as this will be added to the socket
    socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
    socketPath: "/socket.io/",
    title: "Chatbot",
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Comment: Web Chat tag is for Bot Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your Chatwidget through your localhost you need to create a local webserver.
You can do so with e.g. [npm lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server).

Localhost port 5005 is already in use by your rasa server. That's where the chatbot is running.

"*Hello from Rasa: 1.8.1*" shows that the rasa server is working properly.

---

I assume you've used [botfronts rasa-webchat](https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat) as your interface ?

To delete your chathistory you have to implement something like this into the chatwidget:

```
if(Websocket.CLOSED){
localStorage.clear();
//or 
sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

You can find more information in the [rasa-webchat ReadMe API Part](https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat/blob/master/README.md).